# Is there an AUTOSAR Composition-SW-Component-Type in adaptive?

Tags: autosar

I was wondering whether the AUTOSAR Composition-SW-Component-Type will apply to Adaptive i.e. in adaptive AUTOSAR, what do we call a hierarchical grouping of classic and adaptive components?

Answer (score 2):

In theory? Absolutely! If you look at the meta-classes used to model the Executable it is obvious that the CompositionSwComponentType can be used.

In pratice? The time hasn‘t really come yet because of the approach for interaction of application software with the platform modules and the way how API calls identify the caller towards platform modules.

This is not so much due to hard technical limitations, there are probably ways to make it work (in a proprietary solution). But a standardization of these ways is not available.